# Storing HTML in a JS variable but preserving the HTML variables

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Im trying to save some HTML in a JS variable by using the backtick formatting however is it possible to preserve the HTML variable according to the following example

```
var msg = "This is a test" + "\n" + "Test"
```

Im attempting to store this variable as a HTML paragraph while keeping the linebreaks

```
var emsg = '<p style="white-space: pre-wrap;"><\"{msg}"\</p>'
```

But when sending that content in an email to myself (Using Emailjs) I get the following

```
<"{msg}"
```

Any clue what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You are using single quotes (`'`), not backticks (`` ` ``)
2. Placeholders in template literals are indicated by a dollar sign (`$`), which you are missing.

```js
var msg = "This is a test" + "\n" + "Test"

var emsg = `<p style="white-space: pre-wrap;"><\"${msg}"\</p>`

console.log(emsg)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could go with template literals like @spectric showed.
or you can go with simple quote using + to seperate it with `msg` variable

```js
var msg = "This is a test" + "\n" + "Test";//    V     V
var emsg = '<p style="white-space: pre-wrap;"><\"'+msg+'"\</p>';
console.log(emsg);
```

Answer (score 1):

as described + removing the extra `<\"` and `"\` probably

var emsg = `<p style="white-space: pre-wrap;">${msg}</p>`