# {"cod":"400","message":"wrong latitude"} returning when using OpenWeather API

Tags: javascript, openweathermap

This is my code. Whenever I try to check the link, it ends up returning an error message. What can I do to fix this?

```
window.addEventListener('load', ()=>{
    let lon;
    let lat;
    if(navigator.geolocation){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
            lon = position.coords.longitude;
            lat = position.coords.latitude;

            const api = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat={lat}&lon={lon}&appid=432199bc4e2df182e56f173156ed4922
            `;

        });
        
    }else{
        h1.textContent = "NOT WORKING"
    }

});
```

Comment: Where in this code do you ever send a request to the API?

Comment: **All:** It's just a typo-level error. @​AhanaIyer - You're missing the `$` on the substitutions in the [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), so you're *literally* sending it `lat={lat}` and `lon={lon}`. You need `lat=${lat}` and `lon=${lon}`. (Probably better not to have that newline in it as well.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Could you please post your comment as an answer?

Comment: @jnv - This error is already covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69321097/storing-html-in-a-js-variable-but-preserving-the-html-variables/69321125#69321125) (and probably others), there's no need for us to repeat that here (except as a comment to help the OP directly).